# If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb N$ is continuous, then it's constant.

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb N$ is continuous, then it's constant. Th result looks intuitive, but I can't prove it. I try by contradiction : suppose there is $x,y\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $f(x)\neq f(y)$. So in somehow $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq 1$, and thus, using the $\varepsilon -\delta $ definition with $\varepsilon <1$ I tried to get a contradiction, but since there is no reason to have $|x-y|\leq \delta $, I couldn't find a way to write it properly. Can someone give hint ?

Comment: Do you know the Intermediate Value theorem ?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/505472/42969

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Using your method : Suppose $x<y$ and $f(x)\neq f(y)$. Set $z=\inf\{t>x\mid f(t)\neq f(y)\}$. Using continuity of $f$ at $z$ should allow you to get a contradiction.

**Method 2**

$f^{-1}(\{f(0)\})$ is open and closed in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: **Method 3** : Use the IVT ! (+1)

Comment: Method 2 is the best one IMO, as that users the definition directly and it is still the shortest. When that happens it should be savoured.

Comment: @Arthur: What mean IMO ?

Comment: @Surb "in my opinion"

Comment: I agree with you, but it's not sure that it's a good hint for the OP (depending on his/her topological knowledge) :-) @Arthur

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd method but thanks to method 1, I could solve my exercise. Thank you.